# Mysql create virtual column out of result

Tags: mysql

I have 5 table:
`users`
`user_profiles`
`courses`
`user_subjects`
`subjects`

that use to pull related subject for each user using this query:

```
SELECT
    --snip--
    u.id,
    u.username,
    u.level,
    c.name course_expertise,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ) subjects
FROM
    user_profiles up
INNER JOIN users u ON up.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN courses c ON up.course_expertise_id = c.id
INNER JOIN user_subjects us ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN subjects s ON us.subject_id = s.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Resulting in:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
| id | username  | level     | course_expertise                  | subjects          |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|  2 | lecturer  | lecturer  | Information Technology Management | sub1, sub2, sub3  |
|  3 | professor | professor | Information Technology Management | sub4, sub 5, sub6 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Is there a way i can achive something like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | username  | level     | course_expertise                  | subject1 | subject2 | subject3 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  2 | lecturer  | lecturer  | Information Technology Management |   sub1   |   sub2   | sub3     |
|  3 | professor | professor | Information Technology Management |   sub4   |   sub5   | sub6     |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

**Edited**
`subjects` column, will always contain 3 subject

Comment: Is there always only 3 subjects or they can be increased ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid always 3..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only 3 subjects then it will work fine.

```
select ID,
username,
level,
name course_expertise,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(subjects,',','1') subject1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(subjects,',','2'),',','-1') subject2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(subjects,',','3'),',','-1') subject3
 from
(

SELECT
    u.id,
    u.username,
    u.level,
    c.name course_expertise,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ) subjects
FROM
    user_profiles lp
INNER JOIN users u ON lp.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN courses c ON lp.course_expertise_id = c.id
INNER JOIN user_subjects us ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN subjects s ON us.subject_id = s.id
GROUP BY u.id

) A
```

Comment: exactly same i was going to post :)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Can I expect a comment on my solution too? :)

Comment: im currently outside...will accept ur answer as soon as i test it..thx anyway

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Thats fine. I am aware of using `substring_index`. Just suggested a solution using `case` on limited number of items.

Answer (score 1):

**Change**:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ) subjects
```

**To**:

```
max( case when s.name in( 'sub1', 'sub4' ) then s.name else null end ) as 'Subject 1'  
, max( case when s.name in( 'sub2', 'sub5' ) then s.name else null end ) as 'Subject 2'  
, max( case when s.name in( 'sub3', 'sub6' ) then s.name else null end ) as 'Subject 3'
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Cool. But as per your comment on other answer, this can be adoptable if number of unique subjects are limited.

Comment: i dont know subject name before hand, so i guess i cant use this one